# Rearranging rows of data with same value

Tags: r, sorting

I have the following data:

```
Data <- data.frame(Project=c(123,123,123,123,123,123,124,124,124,124,124,124),
               Date=c("12/27/2016 15:16","12/27/2016 15:20","12/27/2016 15:24","12/27/2016 15:28","12/27/2016 15:28","12/27/2016 15:42","12/28/2016 7:22","12/28/2016 7:26","12/28/2016 7:35","12/28/2016 11:02","12/28/2016 11:02","12/28/2016 11:28"),
               OldValue=c("","Open","In Progress","Open","System Declined","In Progress","System Declined","Open","In Progress","Open","Complete","In Progress"),
               NewValue=c("Open","In Progress","System Declined","In Progress","Open","System Declined","Open","In Progress","Complete","In Progress","Open","Complete"))
```

The data is already ordered by Project, then Date.

However, if there are two rows with the same Date (such as rows 4,5 and 10,11) I want to designate the order based on OldValue. So I'd like row 5 ahead of row 4, and row 11 ahead of row 10.

How can I go about doing this?

Comment: Ordering alphabetically will produce different results if `OldValue` is a factor.

Comment: I have tried ordering my data by Project, Date, OldValue and for the most part that works. However, there are instances like in the example above where that would not work ie Rows 4,5

Answer (score 2):

```
#Assign Desired order to the OldValue, CHANGE "y" IF NECESSARY
OldValue_order = data.frame(OldValue = c("","Open","In Progress","System Declined","Complete"), y = c(0,4,2,1,3))

# We'll need lookup command to copy desired order to the "Data"
library(qdapTools)
Data$OV_order = lookup(Data$OldValue, OldValue_order) # Adds new column to "Data"

# Arrange the data.frame in desired order
Data = Data[with(Data, order(Project, as.POSIXct(Date, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"), OV_order)),]

#Remove the added column
Data = Data[1:4]
```